# Should I use at, in or on here: "[At/In/On] the time line you can find"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Which prepositions goes better in the below statement?

> [at/in/on] the time line you can find all info about latest events [in/on] our system.

The time line is area on website, and I want add description about it.

Comment: What's that 'system'? And for *websites*, we generally have things ***'on'*** them. So, it's **On** the timeline, you can find all info about *the* latest events *of* our system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the time line you can find all info about latest events in our
>   systems.

We usually refer to things being "on" a timeline because they're visually displayed with little markers showing events or years *on* that line.

We say something is "in" the system because it shows that information is stored *in*side. Data is inside a system, not on top of it.